# printing data in columns excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to print out 4 arrays into excel using Python. So I used the code below to print out my results. I want 4 columns: Frequency, Max PL, Max P, Gain

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

headings=['Frequency','Max PL 2f0', 'Max PL', 'Gain Flatness']

worksheet.write_row('A1',headings,bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2',Frequency)
worksheet.write_column('B2',Max_PL_2f0)
worksheet.write_column('C2',Max_PL)
worksheet.write_column('D2',GainFlatness)

workbook.close()
```

When I run this code, it gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

When I comment out:

```
worksheet.write_column('D2', GainFlatness)
```

then it works just fine. Gain Flatness is just one number and when I tried making it an array, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

how do I just type one number into a column in excel.

I want my data to look like this, but in excel:
[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciMSF.png) 
I have the first three columns down, I just need to have that one number under Gain Flatness. but it keeps giving me:

```
'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Are you writing to Excel, or just to a csv (i.e. text) file (which you might then open in Excel)?

Comment: What you you want the output to be? If you just want the single numeric value of `GainFlatness` to appear in one cell, why don't you just write it there?

Comment: how would i write to just that one specific cell?
I tried worksheet.write_row('D2',GainFlatness)
but that didn't work and it gave me the same 'numpy.float64' error

Comment: Surely just `worksheet.write('Cell',value)` without the column/row argument.

Comment: Thanks you! now I feel dumb